# Does Python Flask have a cleaner way to manage mimetypes like Express.js?

Tags: python, flask

In Express.js I can configure the whole app to support mimetype json or  form with this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Then in the routers, I just get the values with:

```
function (req, res) {
      fields  =req.body
}
```

In Flask, I must to use something like this for every route:

```
if request.mimetype == 'application/json':
   res = request.get_json()
else:
   res = request.form

firstname = res['firstname']
lastname = res['lastname']
```

but I don't like using if and else this way. Is there another automatic or cleaner way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask got hooks [`before_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.before_request) and [`after_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Flask.after_request). You can do your transformation in `before_request` method.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    # do your work here
```

Comment: using something Flask.g to store the new request ?

Comment: g is one of the options, you can also use flask session for example, maybe you can modify request (haven't tried). Depending on how big data you want to store is.